# Can I control another app from my macOS app?

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm looking to control another app from my macOS app.

I want to

- check tab' URL in a browser (Safari, Chrome)
- change tab' URL from my app

I noticed an app got Automation permission.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html) to get and control browsers and other apps.

AppleScript can get the URLs a browser have been opened and change the tab's URL to what you want.